# SCRIPT5017: Erro de sintaxe em expressão normal

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Quando rodo minha aplicação pelo Chrome ou Firefox ela funciona perfeitamente. Porém pelo IE 10 em determinado momento da aplicação dá esse erro de Javascript.

```
**JavaScript critical error at line 99, column 86 in http://localhost:64146/VoucherRequest/ConfirmRequest?requestId=2862
SCRIPT5017: Erro de sintaxe em expressão normal**
```

// Quando clico nesse botão, no IE, dá a mensagem de erro.

Pesquisei e não encontrei nada esclarecedor sobre. Já conferi a sintaxe, já coloquei a seguinte tag na head

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
```

Enfim, não funciona no meu IE. Preciso de uma luz!

EDIT

VoucherRequest/ConfirmRequest

```
@model Request
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Requisição";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h1>
Requisição</h1>
<h2>
Passo 3:</h2>
<p>
Verifique os dados preenchidos e clique em concluir. Se alguma informação estiver
incorreta, clique em corrigir.</p>
<div class="form">
<div>
    <span class="title">Solicitante:</span><span class="field">@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Usuario.Nome)</span>
</div>

    <span class="title">Observações:</span><span class="field">@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Note)</span></div>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Funcionário
        </th>
        <th>
            Data
        </th>

        <th>
            Quantidade
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (RequestItem item in Model.Items)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Usuario.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Data)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Quantidade)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
<div class="formfooter">
    <input type="button" value="Corrigir" onclick="location.href=@Url.Action("EditRequest", new { requestId = Model.Id })" />
    <input type="button" value="Gerar pedido" onclick="window.open('@Url.Action("ProcessRequest", new { requestId = Model.Id })','_blank');window.location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Home")'" /></div>
```

Comment: Esse @Url.Action... Pega no source gerado como ele foi renderizado, por favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente seus links estão sendo interpretados como uma Regular Expression ("expressão normal"? Sério, Microsoft?). Isso porque as barras do primeiro link e as do segundo se complementam. Para ilustrar, copie esse trecho abaixo no console do Chrome e aperte enter para ver como a string fica:

```
'<input type="button" value="Solicitar" onclick="window.open(\'http://localhost:64146/VoucherRequest/ConfirmRequest?requestId=2862\',\'_blank\');window.location.href=\'http://localhost:64146/\'" />'
```

Para consertar, tudo que eu fiz foi trocar as aspas simples que cercavam a url por aspas duplas, portanto o código do seu `.cshtml` tem que ser algo assim:

```
<input type="button" value="Solicitar" onclick='window.open("@Url.Action("ProcessRequest", new { requestId = Model.Id })","_blank");window.location.href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")"' /></div>
```